# Stripe Simple Checkout integration with cancel button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe with my website with "Simple" checkout as described at https://stripe.com/docs/checkout . I have created a summary page on which I have added script tag. This shows the Pay With Card and it works fine.

However, I need a "Cancel" or "Back" button on this summary page so as to give user chance to go back to previous page or cancel online booking. But even when this other button is clicked, the Payment pop-up is opened and it is not raising the back button event.

What am I missing? Why even other buttons are hijacked by Stripe JS. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Checkout allows the user to enter their credit card, then creates a token, then immediately submits the `<form></form>` which encloses it. If you need more customizability than that, you'll need to use the [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) integration.

With the Custom integration, the user is presented with Checkout, Stripe generates a token, then it is up to you to decide what to do next --- you could write JS in the token creation callback to append a hidden field with the token and then immediately submit the form, or you could land the user back on your summary page and wait for the user to give an additional confirmation before submitting your form, or 'go back.'

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_xxxyyyyzz',
  token: function(token) {
    // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
    // Do something with that token (append a hidden input + submit the form?)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I can go with custom integration. However, I fail to understand why my other button on the page where there is Stripe Checkout JS is integrated is not posting to server just like normal asp.net button. Why even that is opening the payment pop-up?
Stripe JS should only bind with the input created by it i.e. Pay With Card button...

Comment: Huh, I haven't seen that behavior before when integrating Stripe --- another button on the page opening a Stripe Checkout simple integration. If you're seeing that could be worth emailing a link or example code to Stripe.

Comment: Thanks, will write to stripe support.